# Smarty localization label - how to use in php?

Tags: php, localization, smarty

Im using smarty localization to get language labels

```
{config_load file="localization.conf" section=$project->lang}
```

When I need some label from localization.conf I will put into smarty template file (tpl)
ex. `{#label#}` (where label in `localization.conf` = `'some text'`)

But now I need to use label in php file , How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use config variables before output (assume html output) you can load config in php

```
$smarty->configLoad('test.conf', 'Login');

var_dump($smarty->getConfigVars());   

$smarty->display('test.tpl');
```

Those config data loaded via PHP will be also visible in Smarty templates. More info: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.config.vars.tpl